# Compute the power function for upper tail t-test in R

Tags: r

I have  a random sample from normal distribution with sigma is known. The null hypothesis is to test mu<=500 versus mu > 500 at alpha=.05 level.

sigma= 100, n = 40 and alpha = 0.05, I would like to use 1000 simulated samples to estimate **power function** for mu when mu between [450, 700) for the t-test.

Then I want to plot the estimated power curve for mu taking a sequence of values in the interval with an increment 10, i.e.,mu = 450,460, . . . ,690,700.

This is my code. I would like someone to tell me if what I am doing here is right approach. I was not sure if the way I calculated the power is correct. Thank you very much

```
##power analysis t test
set.seed()

##power analysis t test
set.seed(2017)
n<-1000
samplesize<-40
sigma<-100
## alternate hypothesis
mu<-seq(from=450,to=690,by=10)
test_t<-matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=1)
power_t<-matrix(0,nrow=length(mu),ncol=1)
for( k in 1:length(mu))
{
for ( i in 1:n)
{
a<-rnorm(samplesize,mu[k],sigma)
test_t[i]<-(mean(a)-500)/sqrt(var(a)/length(a))
}
z_t<-qt(0.95,samplesize-1)<=test_t
power_t[k]<-length(z_t[z_t])/n
}


jpeg(file=paste("G:\\Routput\\Power analysis t test ",".jpg",sep=""))
print(plot(mu,power_t,main=("Power analysis t test"),xlab="mu",ylab="rejection rate",cex.main=1.5,cex.lab=1.5))
```

Comment: Not sure on how you're reducing 1000 values to a single value for each outer loop iteration. Besides I don't see an `effect size` specification. You could use the `pwr.t.test` from `pwr` package to compute the power. For more details check - [Power Analysis for one-sample t-test](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/power-analysis-for-one-sample-t-test/)

Comment: Simulating this seems like overkill.  The power formus isn't particularly difficult.  I have my notes from grad school online at http://nutterb.github.io/ItCanBeShown/t-test.html. as mentioned above, the `pwr` package has a good implementation of this. `power.t.test` will do it as well, but the approach isn't as friendly